# Dynamics 365: Refresh a KB Search Control in Javascript

Tags: javascript, microsoft-dynamics

I use KB Search Control to launch a search from Js, using the following code:

```
kbSearchControl.setSearchQuery(queryStr);
kbSearchControl.openSearchResult(1);
```

My problem is that I'm trying to refresh the component to display the query string and results in it, but I can't seem to find a way to do it, any ideas?
Thank you in advance!